# Expanding Xcode while installing Xcode 8 beta 2 on El Capitan

Tags: ios, xcode, installation, osx-elcapitan, xcode8-beta2

I'm trying to install `Xcode_8_beta_2.xip` file downloaded from Apple official site. It shows `Expanding Xcode...verifiying digital signature` shown below :

[image: Screenshot 1]

Thereafter it shows `'The operation couldn't be completed. cipo read error: Undefined error:0'` shown below :

[image: Screenshot 2]

I'm installing on OS X El Capitan 10.11.4. There is already an Xcode 7.3 successfully installed on same system.

I've referred this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25996484/xcode-wont-start-stuck-on-verifying-xcode) but none worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [release notes for Xcode 8 beta](https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=xcode-8-beta-rn), the .xip file can only be extracted on OS X 10.11.5 or newer:

> Expanding Xcode beta’s .xip requires macOS version 10.11.5 or later. Attempting to expand the archive on earlier versions of macOS will result in an error. (26756225)

Comment: Xcode 8 having problem while expanding on OS X 10.11.5 . It says the operation could not be completed. Now it takes 3GB. How to remove the expanded flies. Can you please help me ? @bdash